# java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<404> in jersey restful services unit test

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, rest, junit

I have this class **JerseySpringSuiteTest.java**:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ ProductTest.class })
public class JerseySpringSuiteTest {
    public static JerseyTest jerseyTest;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        jerseyTest = new JerseyTest(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.product.resource")
                .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml").servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
                .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class).requestListenerClass(RequestContextListener.class).build()) {

        };
    }
}
```

and **ProductTest.java**:

```
public class ProductTest{

    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        JerseySpringSuiteTest.jerseyTest.setUp();
        ExecutorService productExecutorService = ContextLoaderListener.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getBean(
                "productExecutorService", ExecutorService.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(productExecutorService);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNoAction() {
        WebResource webResource = JerseySpringSuiteTest.jerseyTest.resource();
        String responseMsg = webResource.path("product/").get(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("No Action Specified", responseMsg);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetProducts() throws URISyntaxException {
        WebResource webResource = JerseySpringSuiteTest.jerseyTest.resource().path(
                "Products/rest/product/getProducts/1/productName/01-01-2013/");
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

and **Product.java:**

```
@Component
@Path("/product")
public class Product{
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object noAction() {
        return "No Action Specified";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getProducts/{companyID}/{companyName}/{date}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object getProducts(@PathParam("companyID") final int companyID,
            @PathParam("date") final String date, @PathParam("companyName") final String companyName)
            throws IOException {
        return productService.getProducts(companyID, companyName, date);
    }
}
```

When I execute it I see:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:542)
    at com.product.resource.MonitoringEngineResourceTest.testGetProducts(ProductTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am able to get data when I ping URL in browser.

Could some one please help me to get response status as 200 and JSON object?

**NOTE:** I am using jersey 1.17.1 version and grizzly2 container.

Comment: 404 means the service returned [*"Not Found"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) - maybe the resource URL is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to your `noAction` unit test, the correct URL seems to be:

```
webResource.path("product/")
```

This is also confirmed by your actual service class:

```
@Path("/product")
public class Product {
   //...
}
```

This means that you need to change your other test to use the same path.

Also, it is `companyName`, not `productName` as per your service class.

```
@Test
public void testGetProducts() throws URISyntaxException {

    WebResource webResource = JerseySpringSuiteTest.jerseyTest.resource();
    ClientResponse response =
        webResource.path("product/getProducts/1/companyName/01-01-2013/")
                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);

    Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
}
```

One possible reason that it works in a browser is that your server (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) is configured to add the common URL prefix `Products/rest` to all paths. This server is not in the picture when you execute unit tests.